# What does it mean for two vector spaces to be equal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I noticed that the dual space of the dual space of a vector space is equal to the vector space itself. From my understanding, the dual of the dual of the vector space contains functions defined on the dual, but functions nonetheless. How can the dual of the dual be considered the same as the original vector space? If I chose my vector space as $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the usual operations it certainly isn't a space of functions!

Comment: They aren't literally equal. But there is an isomorphism from one to the other which is nice enough that you can pretend that they are, by identifying every element of the former space with its image under this isomorphism. This is an abuse of notation, of course, and whenever you identify two spaces (or sets, or anything) like this, you should keep it in mind and make sure that you don't accidentally identify two different spaces in more than one way (thus, indirectly, identifying several distinct elements of one of the sets with each other).

Comment: You'll see many such abuses of notation in algebra. For example, a polynomial in two variables $x,y$ can be considered as a polynomial in one variable $x$ whose coefficients are polynomials in $y$ (or vice versa). This, too, is not a literal equality (a bivariate polynomial is not a univariate polynomial) but a "natural isomorphism". Most of these abuses are harmless, but some are legitimately confusing (of course, it depends on their user -- this isn't very objective). I personally consider the abuse you suggested (i.e., identifying a space with its double dual) to be among ...

Comment: ... the more confusing ones, since (as you said) it makes any vector into a function, leading to infinite recursion when the functions themselves are revealed to operate on functions ("functions all the way down").

Comment: Thanks. Your comment is a good complement to Chris'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dual $V^*$ of a vector space $V$ is the space of *linear* functions on $V$. The dual of the dual (the double dual) is the space of linear functions on the dual space.

For $v\in V$ you can define an element of the double dual using a map $\phi:V\to V^{**}$

$$
\phi(v)(\alpha) = \alpha(v) \quad \forall \alpha\in V^*
$$

For each $v\in V$ this defines a linear map from $V^*\to\mathbb{R}$ (you should check this) so $V$ can be thought of as a space of linear functions over $V^*$.

Note that proving that $V$ is isomorphic to $V^{**}$ is [not completely trivial](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/meta.doubledual.html).

Comment: I think it would be good to add that spaces are not generally isomorphic anyway. (The linked document does of course explain that.)